# Fundamental questions on chance-constrained problem

Tags: probability, optimization, stochastic-processes, stochastic-programming

Chance-constrained is an optimization problem that ensures,  probability of meeting a constraint is above a certain level. The formulation of this problem is generally defined as :

$ \min \mathbb E_\zeta[f(x,\zeta)] \tag{1}$  such that  $$P(h(x, \zeta) \geq 0) \geq \alpha  $$

Where $P$ is the probability function and $\alpha$ is a reliability index between $[0,1]$.

Q1) Is it possible to consider violation of an equality constraint in chance constrained problem as well?
For instance, if $h(x,\zeta)\ge 0$ was an equality constraint, could we still formulate the chance constrained problem as :

$$ \min \mathbb E_\zeta[f(x,\zeta)] \quad\text{ such that } \quad P(h(, \zeta) = 0) \geq \alpha$$

Q2) It is often said in the literature by setting $\alpha=0.5$, the solution of the chance-constrained problem $(1)$ is equal to the deterministic representation of the problem. For example if you have $N$ scenarios $\zeta_{i=1:N}$ with probability of $\rho_{i=1:N}$, the solution of (1) for $\alpha=0.5$ is equal to solution of

$$\min \mathbb E_{\mu}[f(x,\mu)] \quad \text{ such that }\quad  h(x, \mu) \geq 0  \quad \text{ where  } \mu = \sum_{i=1}^N \zeta_i \rho_i$$

Is it a strict rule or just when stochastic process is defined by a normal distribution?

Answer (score 1):

Q1) If $\zeta$ is distributed continuously, the probability that $h(x,\zeta)=0$ is zero if $h(x,\zeta)$ is strictly increasing or decreasing in $\zeta$ for all $x$. So it might be impossible to maintain the equality constraint, since it is measure zero that you succeed with a continuous space of outcomes. If $\zeta$ has finite support, you might be able to do this, but for similar reasons, there might be no solution.

Q2) This does not seem true unless $h(x,\zeta)$ is linear in $\zeta$, so that you can ram the expectation operator through. Otherwise, suppose $h(x,\zeta)$ is strictly convex in $\zeta$. Then $\mathbb{E}[h(x,\zeta)] > h(x,\mu)\ge 0$ implies $\mathbb{E}[h(x,\zeta)]>0$ by Jensen's inequality, and the non-linearity seems to matter for deciding whether or not you are close enough to satisfying the constraint. What literature is this?

Comment: 1) Let say  has a finite support  -  >= h  and h>= 0 . The prob. constraint is Pr. (h=0)>= a. Is it possible to convert it to chance constrained under a finite support?
2) The link is for Q2 is here: https://books.google.be/books?id=eMPTGrc4MFEC&pg=PA128&lpg=PA128&dq=deterministic+equivalent+of+chance+cpnstrained+at+50%25&source=bl&ots=PSQKDZdYT-&sig=ACfU3U1RbEI6UwJDthlzhahz0Tn4gMVM0w&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjy89uX-6TqAhXF0aQKHfDIDToQ6AEwAHoECAgQAQ#v=onepage&q=deterministic%20equivalent%20of%20chance%20cpnstrained%20at%2050%25&f=false
An inspection of Eq 3.3.....